# How can I change the import return from react to a specific file extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I need to know if there is a way to process a file type that is included through import in react native, for example:

import Icon from "icons/Icon.svg"

Add some code that changes the return type of the import, for example instead of returning the svg src, return the component already ready, or edit the raw svg, such as the path properties, etc.

Comment: are you using create-react-app?

Answer (score 0):

You can first change the svg file to jsx file, then export the svg like below example:

```
export default function Svg(){
  return <svg>...</svg>
}
```

Then you can use svg like any other component.

Comment: No, I don't think you understood, for example, let's say that in my project I have an icon.svg file, if I import it and try to use it as a component, it will give an error because the xml syntax is not react- native, I was wondering if you can intercept this, treat this svg and return a react component, I've seen people saying that it is possible to do this using a babel plugin, but I didn't find any objective article teaching how to do this, my objective is to intercept imports aimed at the .svg extension and treat the xml with regex or something to convert it into a component react.

Comment: What happens, is that I am using the react-native-svg-transformer dependency in my project, but it works only using the metro, and the expo does not use the metro for react web

Comment: only for android / iOS, instead from the metro config he uses webpack.config, but this dependency doesn’t support the latest web expo sdks, and the author doesn’t seem interested in solving the problem, so I need to find a paleative to solve this, because I already a lot of code written this way, and I need a way to import svgs, that is compatible for both web and mobile, and that allows me to change svg attributes, such as width, height, fill

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, I found out that it was necessary to create a loader to rewrite the imports aimed at svg, now I can use the same way to import icons both in the web expo and in the mobile, I don't know if it's the right way to solve the problem,  the only one I found, but for me it already serves as a temporary solution.

https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-loader/